# Wrap text in .txt file with Python3?

Tags: python, text, txt

Hello I explain my problem, I try to wrap my text in several lines, it's cool the methods work in the terminal, I have a wrap, but the problem is writing in my text file, impossible to wrap the text, I had to turn the function in all directions, I did not succeed, then I post the initial method if someone has an idea I am a taker

```
phrase = "bla bla bla ceci est une phrase beaucoup trop longue pour ce que je doit réellement dire, en fait je peux même dire qu'elle ne sert a rien, mais du coup je doit quand même la tester"

# lim=40
# line = []
# with open("test.txt", "w") as fiche:
#     for s in phrase.split("\n"):
#         if s == "":
#             break
#         word=0 
#         for d in s.split():
#             if word + len(d) + 1 <= lim:
#                 line.append(d)
#                 word += len(d) + 1 
#             else:
#                 print(" ".join(line))
#                 fiche.write(" ".join(line))

#                 line = [d] 
#                 word = len(d)
#         if (len(line)):
#             print(" ".join(line))
#             fiche.write(" ".join(line))

attempt n°2 :

my_wrap = textwrap.TextWrapper(width = 40)
wrap_list = my_wrap.wrap(text=phrase)

with open("test.txt", "w") as fiche:
    for line in wrap_list:
        print(line)
        fiche.write(" ".join(line))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`textwrap.fill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill) that automatically places newlines for you and you can write it directly to file:

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as fiche:
    fiche.write(my_wrap.fill(phrase))
```

and the content of *test.txt* will be:

```
bla bla bla ceci est une phrase beaucoup
trop longue pour ce que je doit
réellement dire, en fait je peux même
dire qu'elle ne sert a rien, mais du
coup je doit quand même la tester
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new line `\n` between the lines

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as fiche:
    for line in wrap_list:
        print(line)
        fiche.write(f'\n{" ".join(line)}')
```

If you don't want spaces between the letters remove the `" ".join`

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as fiche:
    for line in wrap_list:
        print(line)
        fiche.write(f'\n{line}')
```

Or just use `writelines`

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as fiche:
    fiche.writelines('\n'.join(wrap_list))
```

Comment: ahh ok, I'll try this method too, thanks you ;)

Comment: yes the last second is effective thanks you :)